# Excel VBA-Fixing Row to compare

Tags: excel, vba

Thanks to this site I adapted a code for my own needs , this macro allows me to compare specific cells of an X rows with another cells of Y row and there is a match between all cells not only 1 or 2 cells but all cells of that row then it give **1** and **0** if no match is found

- the problem that the macro is comparing row X with Y which what I want but i doesn't compare X with Y+1 or Y+2  , it passes directly to X+1 and compare it with Y+1

**to better understand my problem see below :**

in this image two line with yellow color are identical and in column AO there is 1 infront of the first line and 1 infront of the second line 
[image]

so what is to compare every row with the other rows(X with Y,Y+1,Y+2) and passe on to the next Row and when there is match that is highlighted or returns 1 in column "AO"

**Code :**

```
Sub check()
 Dim check1, check2 As Variant
 Dim l As Long
 Dim ElementsSame As Boolean
   For i = 2 To 74
     check1 = Array(Range("F" & i), Range("G" & i), Range("H" & i), Range("I" 
       & i), Range("J" & i), Range("K" & i), Range("L" & i), Range("M" & i), 
      Range("N" & i), Range("O" & i), Range("P" & i), Range("Q" & i), 
      Range("R" & i), Range("S" & i), Range("T" & i), Range("U" & i), 
      Range("V" & i), Range("W" & i), Range("X" & i), Range("Y" & i), 
      Range("Z" & i), Range("AA" & i), Range("AB" & i), Range("AC" & i), 
      Range("AD" & i), Range("AE" & i), Range("AF" & i), Range("AG" & i), 
       Range("AH" & i), Range("AI" & i), Range("AJ" & i), Range("AL" & i), 
      Range("AM" & i))
For D = 3 To 74
     check2 = Array(Range("F" & D), Range("G" & D), Range("H" & D), Range("I" 
     & D), Range("J" & D), Range("K" & D), Range("L" & D), Range("M" & D), 
     Range("N" & D), Range("O" & D), Range("P" & D), Range("Q" & D), 
     Range("R" & D), Range("S" & D), Range("T" & D), Range("U" & D), 
      Range("V" & D), Range("W" & D), Range("X" & D), Range("Y" & D), 
       Range("Z" & D), Range("AA" & D), Range("AB" & D), Range("AC" & D), 
       Range("AD" & D), Range("AE" & D), Range("AF" & D), Range("AG" & D), 
      Range("AH" & D), Range("AI" & D), Range("AJ" & D), Range("AL" & D), 
       Range("AM" & D))
 ElementsSame = True
 For l = 0 To 32 
   If check1(l) <> check2(l) Then
    ElementsSame = False

    Exit For
 End If
 Next l

If ElementsSame = False Then

  Range("AO" & i) = 1
  Range("AO" & D) = 1 
Else
   Range("AN" & D) = 0 
End If
Next D

Next i
End Sub
```

Anyone can light me about solving this and If anything is not clear about my problem , please feel free to ask

B.R
Polos

Comment: I'd recommend replacing empty cells with a "-" then use a helper column where you concatenate all your columns together. E.g. a simple four column sample would be `x--x` and you can just look for duplicates for `x--x` - your current approach is pretty messy and is bound to get messier!

Comment: @jamheadart thank you for your suggestions, do you Have an example because in my case I'm limited in modification which mean I can't modify this template but I can highlight or use  "AN" /"AO" column to indicate results

Comment: any help regarding this ?

Comment: If you can't modify the existing sheet can you set up another background sheet where you can use something like `=IF(E1="","-",E1)` to fill a sheet with `x` and `-` which you CAN modify. After that use a column at the end like `=E3&F3&G3&H3` and fill it down. Then you can search for duplicates in that column and push back to the AN/AO columns in the non-modifiable sheet

Comment: It's a good Idea but I can't do that , Because if I concatinate the Values togeather , I will face another problem ,macro will find alot of matchs based on length of that value E.G : cells (A,B,C) it's different than cells (B,F,G) but they got the same length which is 3 :( * and I won't do that Because I need to keep their actual position

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this (not tested on my end)?

```
Option Explicit


Sub check()
 Dim check1, check2 As Variant
 Dim i, d As Long

For i = 2 To 74
    check1 = Array(Range("F" & i), Range("G" & i), Range("H" & i), Range("I" _
    & i), Range("J" & i), Range("K" & i), Range("L" & i), Range("M" & i), _
    Range("N" & i), Range("O" & i), Range("P" & i), Range("Q" & i), _
    Range("R" & i), Range("S" & i), Range("T" & i), Range("U" & i), _
    Range("V" & i), Range("W" & i), Range("X" & i), Range("Y" & i), _
    Range("Z" & i), Range("AA" & i), Range("AB" & i), Range("AC" & i), _
    Range("AD" & i), Range("AE" & i), Range("AF" & i), Range("AG" & i), _
    Range("AH" & i), Range("AI" & i), Range("AJ" & i), Range("AL" & i), _
    Range("AM" & i))
        For d = 3 To 74
            check2 = Array(Range("F" & d), Range("G" & d), Range("H" & d), Range("I" _
            & d), Range("J" & d), Range("K" & d), Range("L" & d), Range("M" & d), _
            Range("N" & d), Range("O" & d), Range("P" & d), Range("Q" & d), _
            Range("R" & d), Range("S" & d), Range("T" & d), Range("U" & d), _
            Range("V" & d), Range("W" & d), Range("X" & d), Range("Y" & d), _
            Range("Z" & d), Range("AA" & d), Range("AB" & d), Range("AC" & d), _
            Range("AD" & d), Range("AE" & d), Range("AF" & d), Range("AG" & d), _
            Range("AH" & d), Range("AI" & d), Range("AJ" & d), Range("AL" & d), _
            Range("AM" & d))

            If Join(check1, Chr(0)) = Join(check2, Chr(0)) Then
                Range("AO" & i) = 1
                Range("AO" & d) = 1
            Else
                Range("AN" & d) = 0
            End If
        Next d
Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: your code doesn't return any errors  but it's comparing cells E.G comparing cells 1 for row 2 and row 3 and if it found match it returns directly 1 in colum "AO" and that's not What I want .:D ... but I need  to show 1 only if cells 1 , cells 2 , cells i  for row 1 is exactly the same for row 2 cells 1,cells 2 , cells i .  until now your code got the same function as my code :(

Comment: It should be checking the array as a whole, not individual values

Comment: you mean with a whole as empty ?